# Best method of isolating devices

Tags: motor, dc

I have a 12 V DC motor whose direction is controlled by reversing polarity. I have a simple mechanical switching system that provides that function.

I have added an inexpensive wireless remote control that also provides this functionality.

When wired together to the motor, the remote works but if the switching side is used, it blows the fuse. Since the polarization reverses to control the motor direction, a simple diode will obviously not work.

Looking for any ideas outside of adding a DPDT switch to select between them.

[image]

Comment: please add a wiring diagram

Comment: Just a quick comment. If you wish the reverse motor direction, it is better to use a DC motor driver, such as L298N, which has built in flyback diodes to protect back EMF.

Comment: Do you change the direction while the motor is running? In this case the back EMF voltage adds to the supply voltage. The current through the fuse is much higher until the direction has changed.

Comment: just looking for a way to avoid a physical switch as everything is mounted where it cannot be accessed (except for the left/right dpdt)

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your problem is the lack of galvanic isolation between the remote control receiver and the motor.

It is imperative that the relays alone provide the interface between the remote control receiver and the motor. In other words, the receiver is to control only the relay coils.

You are employing 'H - bridge' motor control, that requires two DPDT relays.

Here's the schematic.

[image]

Here's a simpler solution, employing two SPDT relays, that has the added advantage of motor braking.

[image]

While using the remote, the operational relay is to be switched off before the other one is switched on.

Comment: Not sure I understand this approach.  The motor turn direction is controlled by reversing polarity.  Both the foot switch and the remote control rx provide that exact function.

With the output of the remote rx and the foot switch connected to the motor, the remote cannot handle the reversed polarity on it's output and promptly blows the main fuse.  I can obviously install a dpdt switch to select which option should control the motor but what I was researching is a non-mechanical method of preventing back flow from the foot switch to the output side of the remote rx.

Comment: Hi Barrow, I now understand that you have a clash between foot switch control (shown in your schematic) and wireless remote control. Please furnish details of the switching done by the remote control receiver.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a ‘black box’ rx.  I have no details other than it works as a motor controller.

Comment: No problem, Barrow. I shouldn't have asked that question as the only requirement is polarity reversal of the receiver output. It will work as it should, as long as the foot switches are left alone. Otherwise, the fuse will blow when the polarity of the two outputs clash. No isolation is possible. A selector switch is inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing DPDT relays. If you wire them up like the following, only a single input source can affect the output at once. The output can never be connected together at any moment

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBlGyR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The option of changing the dpdt is a non-starter as these are in an enclosed foot switch assembly...step on left side to turn left, etc.  I just drew them for clarity.